# Ajax Json Data null at Controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm catching the post in my controller, but the `String formData` is null. Because of this, I'm also unable to use the Anti Forgery Attribute, since it seems like all the data is lost. Maybe I shouldn't be using `serialzeArray`?

My Post:

```
    $("#SetCommunicationSettingsForm").submit(function (e) {
            debugger;
            var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
            var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: formURL,
                type: "POST",
                datatype:"json",
                data: postData,
                success: function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    //data: return data from server
                    if (data.success == true) {
                        $("#SaveSuccessful").show();
                        $("#SetCommunicationSettingsFormArea").hide();
                        $("#SumbitCommunicationSettingForm").val('<%: ServiceSite.Resources.Resources.COMMON_CLOSE %>');
                        $("#SumbitCommunicationSettingForm").unbind('click');
                        $("#SumbitCommunicationSettingForm").click(closeCommunicationSettingPopup);
                        $("#CancelCommuncationSettingButton").hide();
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#DeviceCommuncationSettingLocation").html(data);
                    }
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
        });
```

My controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
    //[AuthorizeActionFilter]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken (Salt= "UpdateCommunicationSettings")]
    public ActionResult UpdateCommunicationSettings(String formData)
    {
        //Decode parameters 
        JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Dictionary<String, Object> jsonParams = ser.Deserialize<Dictionary<String, Object>>(formData);

        //verify permissions on server side
        if (((List<string>)Session["AuthorizedActions"]).Contains("EditDeviceCommunicationSettings"))
        {
            // Build DeviceData.DeviceConfigurationSettings from model, pass to DAL to Save
            List<long> deviceIds = GetSelectedDevicesFromSession();

            foreach (long id in deviceIds)
            {

            }

            return PartialView("DeviceCommunicationSettingDialog");
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { notAuthorized = true });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are posting a json object and not a string.
 So you can technically convert you json into a string with:

```
var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(json);
```

Instead of doing that, try using FormCollection:

```
public ActionResult UpdateCommunicationSettings(FormCollection formData)
{
}
```

You need to drop the serializing.

P.s. you can use a class with the same schema as the json you have on you client, and it will deal with the binding.